# Android studio generates but does not see data binding classes

Tags: android, kotlin

It gets me all the time. I have the latest Android studio 4.0 and sometimes (It happens randomly) android studio argues on my databinding imports as not existing. The thing is that they do exist and app works fine, but because studio acts with those imports as non existing, I can not use autocomplete and many other thing while writing code. Sometimes it disapears randomly when reopening program, sometimes not.

Comment: try to clean and rebuild project and it works :))

Comment: It's sad how often this still happens. I have to clean/rebuild every few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this (not necessarily only about data binding or Kotlin), in many versions of Android Studio. I don't have a definitive answer, but to me it mostly seems that it is caused by computer being overloaded (low on RAM) and generated files being corrupt, like Android Studio gets confused when it gets stuck and corrupts it self. Yup it happens, even on my 24GB work machine, Android Studio can eat up all the RAM sometimes, and mess up whole lotta things. And I've mostly seen this on Windows (multiple times) and once or twice on Linux. Never happened on a Mac for me. In most cases simple *restart of Android Studio & a computer reboot* helps, sometimes *Invalidating caches and restarting* is enough too. If it doesn't help, reinstall Android Studio.